# a/the/my travel - the usage

Tags: usage

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/travel here you can read this:

• Travel is only used as an uncountable noun. **✗Don’t say: a travel | the travel**

• Travels is always used as a plural noun in this meaning. **✗Don’t say: her travel | my travel**

But I come across natives saying "I can enjoy my travel without...."

Why is it that the dictionary's advice is neglected in reality?

Comment: These natives (of where?) must be using _travel_ as an uncountable noun 'the activity of travelling' rather than speaking of an individual journey.

Comment: So if I want to talk about an individual journey I should NOT say "my travel"?

Comment: No, you shouldn't (say 'journey'!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would normally be considered an error to say:

> "I can enjoy my travel without...."

This doesn't mean that native speakers never use such constructions (everyone makes mistakes) but (1) they are rare, normally one would say "enjoy my journey" or "enjoy my holiday", and (2) You would be judged by other native speakers.

Now you may not care what other people think and that's okay; many native speakers don't care much. But if you are trying to speak correctly, you should avoid this construction.

It might be worth noting that it is quite common to use "travel" as a noun adjunct in expressions like "enjoy my travel writing" or "enjoy my travel blog".

Thus "travel" is a defective noun.  It has countable and uncountable senses, but the countable sense (meaning a series of journies) is only used in the plural.  The uncountable sense can't usually be determined with words like "my" or the.

Comment: "The uncountable form can't usually be determined with words like "my" or the." What? Why not? You can say for example: Here is the news, They were all anxious to increase their knowledge

Comment: The uncountable sense *of the word travel* is not normally determined with "my".  Of course other uncountable nouns often have such determiners.  @Kjaamond

Comment: There definitely are situations (dialects? jargons?) where *travel* is modified by a possessive. In my on-the-job experience (in the US), it is 100% idiomatic to say things like, “Has **Jim’s travel** to Salt Lake City been approved?” where *travel* is essentially synonymous with *trip*. Likewise, “I completed **my travel** without any major headaches.” I note though that we would not say something like \*”His **next** travel is to  Washington.”